# receive all matching networks for IP address from postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cidr

I have a postgres db with a table `networks` which includes a column `network` of type cidr. I want to queue all networks which contain an IP address I provide. I couldnt find how to do this.

Currently I pull all networks, and then use the `include?` method IPAddr class provides:

```
Network.all.each{|row| pp row if row.network.include?("10.176.0.5")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use postgres' `>>=` operator (includes or equal) or `>>`(includes) that is defined for cidr type:

```
Network.where(['network >> ?', "10.176.0.5"])
```

Comment: this works partially. It returns only one network even though there are 3 networks in the table which should match. I guess it returns only one by default ?

Comment: without "=" it works perfectly. Thanks a lot ! Network.where(['network >> ?', "10.176.0.5"])